# How do I change the CSV data to a float?

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that is meant to read a CSV file that has data in it. I get this error message when I run the program, "ValueError: could not convert string to float:" How can I make my strings into floats?

```
,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r = np.loadtxt('car.txt', delimiter = '\s', unpack = True)
plt.plot(o,r, label='Loaded from file!')

plt.xlabel('o')
plt.ylabel('r')
plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: You should  `pandas` and plot from there.  `df = pd.read_csv('car.txt)`.  Additionally, include the top 5 lines of the csv, so we can see what you're trying to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Python use `float()` function to convert a string into a float. The `ValueError`  happens when Python doesn't know how to do so

for example

```
float("1.234") # return 1.234
float("1.45  ") # return 1.45
```

but if you do

```
float("abc")
```

This will cause a ValueErrror since Python doesn't know how to convert it.

Back to your question, maybe try to print your variable and check if it is valid to be converted to float.

Answer (score -1):

if all your data are float, maybe:
1,the first rou are names not float
2,maybe there are 'backspace' in your data, they will be recognize as '/t', find a spack in your data,press ctrl+r,change backspace to space